# React Form with i18n-iso-countries package, input is in different language than list of countries

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with a field for selecting a country. I used the package mentioned above but there's a slight issue.

The list of countries is in German, but when the user starts typing the country they want to choose, the results get filtered only when you type in English.

So for example, rather than typing in "Südafrika", the user has to type in "South Africa" in order for that result to be filtered, despite the result being shown in the German "Südafrika".

I was wondering if I can target the input field and set the language to German but that doesn't seem to be an option. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You can try custom onChange method and filter the list based on selected language (navigator.language)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.